# Need explanations on these lines of text on the intent and passing of object

Tags: java, android, object, android-intent, bundle

Hello can explain to me why in this code that I found on the internet we use bundle? Why do not we put the object directly into the intent? This has to do with the speed of execution?

```
Contact contact = new Contact();    
Intent intent = new Intent(); 
        Bundle args = new Bundle(); 
        args.putSerializable("contact", (contact)); 
        intent.putExtra("BUNDLE", args);
```

Why bundle and not directly this way?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(); 
    intent.putExtra("contact", contact);
```

Comment: The receiver expects a bundle. Thats all. Of course you could transfer such info without. But it has been designed and implemented that way.

Answer (score 0):

Because intent putExtra can't take your Contact directly. If want to pass your Contact implement Serializable interface like below

```
public class Contact implements Serializable{

}
```